Convergence of the integral of $\log(1-x^n)$ on $[0,1]$
Prove or disprove the convergence of the following integral
$$
\int_0^1 \log(1-x^n) dx .
$$
My first thought was to use Taylor series for the integrand. More precisely, since
$$
\int_0^1 \log(1-x^n) dx 
= -\int_0^1 \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{x^{mn}}{m}
=-\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m(mn+1)}
$$which is convergent having the same nature as the series of general term $1/m^2$. Am I missing something?

Your proof is fine. A simpler one is: $|\log(1-x^n)|\le|log(1-x)|$ and $\int_0^1|\log(1-x)|dx=1<\infty$.

Yes, you forgot about the fact that the for limit under the integral sign you need uniform convergence, but generally speaking the Taylor series diverges at point 1

Fortunately, here you don't need uniform convergence, since all terms have the same constant sign.

Why you said that only from the constant sing of the involed functions allow me to neglect the uniform convergence (which I think it is not present here)?

@user217519 Because then one can use monotone convergence.

If I understand well, denoting $f_n(x)=\log(1-x^n)$, then $f_n > f_{n+1}$, thus by monotone convergence theorem we can pass the limit under the integral sign. Or there is something else?

$\displaystyle \Re\left(1 \over n\right) > 0$.

Noting that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m(m n+1)} & =\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m}-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{m n+1} \\
& =\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+\frac{1}{n}}\right) \\
& =\psi\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)+\gamma ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\zeta(.) $ is the zeta function.
Therefore the integral is convergent.

Who is the function $\psi$?
